# How do I sort a vector of pairs based on the second element of the pair?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

If I have a vector of pairs:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec;
```

Is there and easy way to sort the list in **increasing** order based on the second element of the pair?

I know I can write a little function object that will do the work, but is there a way to use existing parts of the *STL* and `std::less` to do the work directly?

EDIT:  I understand that I can write a separate function or class to pass to the third argument to sort.  The question is whether or not I can build it out of standard stuff.  I'd really something that looks like:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::something_magic<int, int, std::less>());
```

Comment: Here is an example:<br>
[std::sort in a vector of pairs](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-325645.html)

Comment: c++ doesn't have lamdas so you can't do exactly what you want, you'll need to create a separate function/functor. This can be a one-liner so it really shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: C++ has lambdas now! Woo!

Answer (score 269, accepted):

**EDIT**: using c++14, the best solution is very easy to write thanks to lambdas that can now have parameters of type `auto`. **This is my current favorite solution**

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &left, auto &right) {
    return left.second < right.second;
});
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

Just use a custom comparator (it's an optional 3rd argument to `std::sort`)

```
struct sort_pred {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int,int> &left, const std::pair<int,int> &right) {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sort_pred());
```

If you're using a C++11 compiler, you can write the same using lambdas:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::pair<int,int> &left, const std::pair<int,int> &right) {
    return left.second < right.second;
});
```

**EDIT**: in response to your edits to your question, here's some thoughts ...
if you **really** wanna be creative and be able to reuse this concept a lot, just make a template:

```
template <class T1, class T2, class Pred = std::less<T2> >
struct sort_pair_second {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<T1,T2>&left, const std::pair<T1,T2>&right) {
        Pred p;
        return p(left.second, right.second);
    }
};
```

then you can do this too:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sort_pair_second<int, int>());
```

or even

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sort_pair_second<int, int, std::greater<int> >());
```

Though to be honest, this is all a bit overkill, just write the 3 line function and be done with it :-P

Comment: Keep in mind that this is different from `operator<` in `pair<T1,T2>`. The default comparator uses *both* first and second element (in case first ones are equal). Here only the second one is being used.

Comment: @Googol: That's precisely what the OP asked for... He said:

`"is there and easy way to sort the list in increasing order based on the second element of the pair?"`

Comment: @evan-teran, yes, I know. I was only indicating that if both seconds elements are equal, then the result can be confusing (if used for sorting, for example). This problem is not suffered by the default comparator because it uses the second element for tie-breaking. I reached this question looking for a comparator that used the second element as main information for comparing, but I also needed that it used the first one for tie-breaking, so I'd like to avoid others miss that point (as I, in fact, did).

Answer (score 71):

You can use boost like this:

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), 
          boost::bind(&std::pair<int, int>::second, _1) <
          boost::bind(&std::pair<int, int>::second, _2));
```

I don't know a standard way to do this equally short and concise, but you can grab `boost::bind` it's all consisting of headers.

Comment: +1 for using Boost. Btw, with a modern compiler you could probably already replace boost with std::tr1 as this will be in the standard soon.

Comment: unfortunately, i tried the same with gcc trunk's c++1x std::bind, and it failed because it doesn't have the op< for bind. dunno however whether what c++1x says about this. probably it tells you to use lambda for that :)

Comment: I suppose boost isn't standard, but it's close enough.  :-)

Comment: Posted a followup questions to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4184917/220636

Answer (score 49):

Its pretty simple
you use the sort function from algorithm and add your own compare function

```
vector< pair<int,int > > v;
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),myComparison);
```

Now you have to make the comparison based on the second selection 
so declare you "myComparison" as

```
bool myComparison(const pair<int,int> &a,const pair<int,int> &b)
{
       return a.second<b.second;
}
```

Comment: Simple and  "to-the-point". Doesn't need boost or a specific C++ version. +1

Comment: This should be marked as the best solution. Doesn't need c++14 to implement it.

Comment: Can you explain to me how this comparison works? Are we passing two elements to the myComparision at a time then how is it able to sort? Also, What role does a.second<b.second play?

Comment: The myComparison function is called by the sort function where the sort function sends two value and expect a True or False in order for it to determine which should be placed first and which element should be placed second, so that is how the comparison function helps the developer to define his own definition of greater than and less than

Answer (score 30):

With C++0x we can use lambda functions:

```cpp
using namespace std;
vector<pair<int, int>> v;
        .
        .
sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
     [](const pair<int, int>& lhs, const pair<int, int>& rhs) {
             return lhs.second < rhs.second; } );
```

In this example the return type `bool` is implicitly deduced.

**Lambda return types**

When a lambda-function has a single statement, and this is a return-statement, the compiler can deduce the return type. From C++11, §5.1.2/4:

> ...
>
> - If the compound-statement is of the form `{ return expression ; }` the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
> - otherwise, `void`.

To explicitly specify the return type use the form `[]() -> Type { }`, like in:

```cpp
sort(v.begin(), v.end(),
     [](const pair<int, int>& lhs, const pair<int, int>& rhs) -> bool {
             if (lhs.second == 0)
                 return true;
             return lhs.second < rhs.second; } );
```

Comment: Why `if (lhs.second == 0)`?

Comment: No particular meaning;  `lhs.second < rhs.second` may return `true` or `false` and the compiler can clearly deduce `bool`. Just wanted to demonstrate the `[]() -> Type { }` case.

Comment: At least with clang, this implicit deduction may not work properly, I had to add ->bool as the lambda return type to get it working properly.

Answer (score 5):

For something reusable:

```
template<template <typename> class P = std::less >
struct compare_pair_second {
    template<class T1, class T2> bool operator()(const std::pair<T1, T2>& left, const std::pair<T1, T2>& right) {
        return P<T2>()(left.second, right.second);
    }
};
```

You can use it as

```
std::sort(foo.begin(), foo.end(), compare_pair_second<>());
```

or

```
std::sort(foo.begin(), foo.end(), compare_pair_second<std::less>());
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to rely on a non standard [select2nd](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/select2nd.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try swapping the elements of the pairs so you can use `std::sort()` as normal.