# Help understanding boost::bind placeholder arguments

Tags: c++, boost

I was reading a StackOverFlow post regarding sorting a vector of pairs by the second element of the pair. The most obvious answer was to create a predicate, but one answer that used boost caught my eye.

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), 
  boost::bind(&std::pair<int, int>::second, _1) <
  boost::bind(&std::pair<int, int>::second, _2));
```

I've been trying to figure out how boost::bind works, or at least just how to use it, but I can't figure out what the purpose of the placeholder arguments _1 and _2 are, and the boost documentation doesn't sink in at all.

Could anyone explain this specific usage of boost::bind?

P.S. Original question: [How do I sort a vector of pairs based on the second element of the pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279854/how-do-i-sort-a-vector-of-pairs-based-on-the-second-element-of-the-pair)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This expression:

```
boost::bind(&std::pair<int, int>::second, _1) <
boost::bind(&std::pair<int, int>::second, _2)
```

namely, the use of the `<` operator actually defines a functor between two other functors, both of which defined by `bind`.

The functor expected by sort needs to have an `operator()` which looks like this:

```
bool operator()(const T& arg1, const T& arg2);
```

when you're creating a functor using boost's `<` then the name holders `_1` and `_2` correspond to `arg1` and `arg2` of the functor you're creating.

The `bind` call create a functor that calls `::second` of `arg1` and `arg2`

With any luck, the introduction of lambdas in C++0x will make expressions like this obsolete.

Comment: For the record: `typedef std::pair<int, int> pair_type; std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](pair_type x, pair_type y){ return x.second < y.second; });`

Answer (score 5):

std::sort requires a binary predicate to compare two items from the range. The placeholders show where the first and the second argument are going to be used.

boost::bind makes it so that the entire expression reads as `_1.second < _2.second` (except since the . operator is not overloadable, such expressiveness cannot be achieved).

Both bind calls, in this case, create a function object that accepts a `pair<int, int>` and returns the value of `second`. `operator<` in turn is overloaded to return another binary functor that compares the results of the previous functors. And that gets used by `std::sort`.