# Sorting on pairs in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, std-pair

I am writing a code for activity schedule problem. If i store the starting time and finishing time in an array of pairs like `pair<int,int>p[10]`  and after this i need to sort the activities as per finishing time with increasing finishing time,omitted the part where it asks user to input and then make pair for simplicity,hope it won't be a problem for the guy to answer  so i apply `sort(p,p+n)` where n means no of activities ,i don't get like will it sort all starting activities this way or the finishing activities this way.So this is the code.`pair <int,int>p[10]
Sort(p,p+6)`

Comment: I have omitted the part of code where we ask user to input and make pair to make pairs

Comment: What is your question, are you asking for someone to write sort for you?

Comment: Also why dont you just use a `map` or a `set`?

Comment: No i just want to know if i apply the sort on a pair which stores two integers like (1,6)(8,7)(6,10) then what would be the resulting pair.Will it get sorted on 1,8,6 or 6,7,10 .

Comment: Yes i tried but could not understand that's why i am asking it on stackoverflow

Comment: Ok, so how about you show us what you tried, did you write some compilable code that performed a sort?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a vector of pairs based on the second element of the pair?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279854/how-do-i-sort-a-vector-of-pairs-based-on-the-second-element-of-the-pair)

Comment: Wait Ben i am writing an answer to it.Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting `pair`, the first items are compared and only when they are equal, the second ones are compared. So this won't sort it by the finishing time but by the starting time. But `sort` can have a third argument which is a method used for sorting (it returns whether the first argument is before the the second). Pass there a lambda that will compare second items (finishing time).

Answer (score 0):

It sorts the activities in the increasing order of their starting  time i.e the first elements in every pair is compared to the first element in second pair and so on. .Suppose (7,9),(0,10),(4,5),(8,9),(4,10),(5,17) are the starting time and finishing time then after sorting the result would be (0,10)(4,5),(4,10),(5,17),(7,9),(8,9).