# sorting of pairs by first element

Tags: c++

```
#include<cstdio>
 #include<vector>
 #include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

 struct myclass
{
    bool operator()(pair<int,int> &left, pair<int,int> &right)
    {
        return (left.first < right.first);
    }
 } x;

int main()
{
     int i;
     vector<pair<int,int> > a;
    a.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
    a.push_back(make_pair(1,0));
    a.push_back(make_pair(2,2));
    a.push_back(make_pair(2,1));
     a.push_back(make_pair(3,2));
    a.push_back(make_pair(1,5));

sort(a.begin(),a.end(),x);
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    printf("%d %d\n",a[i].first,a[i].second);
}
return 0;
}
```

what is the problem with my code sorting vector of pairs by first element ?
It is giving [Error] expected primary-expression before 'x' .

Comment: What's `myclass x` supposed to mean?

Comment: object of class myclass .

Comment: You can get some hints here [How do I sort a vector of pairs based on the second element of the pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279854/how-do-i-sort-a-vector-of-pairs-based-on-the-second-element-of-the-pair)

Comment: The newest version of the code works as is.

Comment: Your code, as it currently standards does not produce that error; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/755a9f0655f68cf9

Comment: In my compiler It is giving [Error] expected primary-expression before 'x' .

Comment: Dev c++ 5.7.1 compiler

Comment: Which means you are using Orwell Dev-C++ which in uses recent versions of `g++`, the same is used by coliru.

Comment: Btw, `std::pair` already has a lexicographical order, so in presented case, you may use default comparer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b99b3ac8d24ab49).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using IntPair = pair<int, int>;

int main()
{
    vector<IntPair> a = {
        make_pair(1,2),
        make_pair(1,0),
        make_pair(2,2),
        make_pair(2,1),
        make_pair(3,2),
        make_pair(1,5)
    };

    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const IntPair &left, const IntPair &right)
         {
             return (left.first < right.first);
         });

    for(auto const & i : a)
    {
        cout << i.first << ' ' << i.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

You don't need the class you have defined nor the global variable `x`.  With modern C++, you don't have to define a [functionoid](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#functionoids) or a [functor](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#functor-vs-functionoid) explicitly, just use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: sir but why it gives error in my solution " expected primary-expression before 'x'"

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by the "You don't need the class" and the long line of code.

Comment: No problem, I didn't add much explanation to the code, so partly my bad too :)