# Using std::sort_heap on a vector of pair

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, heapsort

I want to implement the Fast Tagging algorithm described in Section 5.2 of 
http://physbam.stanford.edu/~fedkiw/papers/stanford2001-03.pdf. Here,  they claim to use a binary heap for sorting operations, so I thought it could be a good idea to use the sort_heap method of the standard library as explained here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort_heap/

in this example the vector to be sorted contains just integer values while in my case I have a distance map defined on a 3D grid (linearized into a 1D array) and, since I have to know the index corresponding to a particular distance value, I should use something like:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,float>> v;
```

In this thread

[How do I sort a vector of pairs based on the second element of the pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279854/how-do-i-sort-a-vector-of-pairs-based-on-the-second-element-of-the-pair)

it's shown how to call std::sort for a similar problem, is it possible to do the same for std::sort_heap?

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

As T.C. pointed out this problem can be solved by using a priority_queue!

Comment: The description feels like they are using a priority queue. `sort_heap` does something different.

Comment: OK! Thanks! This answered my question!

Comment: If the question is answered, one of you should provide the answer, then you can accept it, @FedericoNardi.