# Sort vector of pairs: No matching function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, std-pair

I have followed the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279854/how-do-i-sort-a-vector-of-pairs-based-on-the-second-element-of-the-pair) to sort a vector of pairs.

And I get

```
linear_problem.h:275:

error: no matching function for call to

‘sort(std::vector<std::pair<int, double> >::iterator,
std::vector<std::pair<int, double> >::iterator, <unresolved overloaded
function type>)’
     std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compareFunc);
```

The class with the code is:

```
class Coefficients{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> data;

public:
    Coefficients(){}
    bool compareFunc(const std::pair<int, double> &a, const std::pair<int, double> &b){
        return a.first > b.first;
    }

    void sort(){
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compareFunc);
    }

};
```

I have no idea of what can be wrong since the code is quite like the example.

Comment: `compareFunc` is a member function of `Coefficients`. It can only be called with an object of type `Coefficients` which `std::sort` doesn't have. Did you mean to put the comparison function outside of `Coefficients` or make it `static`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compareFunc()` is a member function and requires an instance of `Coefficients` to be called.

You can make it a `static` class member function to solve that problem:

```
    static bool compareFunc(const std::pair<int, double> &a, const std::pair<int, double> &b){
 // ^^^^^^
        return a.first > b.first;
    }

    void sort(){
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), &Coefficients::compareFunc);
                                         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
```

Comment: excellent, this works. Since I don't have that much experience in C++, I didn't know what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

using c++14, the best solution is very easy to write thanks to lambdas

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &left, auto &right) {
    return left.second < right.second;
});
```

or you can use comparator like:

```
struct comp{
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int,int> &left, const std::pair<int,int> &right) {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp());
```